# Installing dse 3.1 dependency

Tags: datastax-enterprise

When I run '*sudo apt-get install dse-full*', I am getting dependency/configuration issues,  Full output listed below.

I had a previous version of dse & opscenter installed and I did manually delete the config files located in /etc/dse earlier, which is the probably the root cause of my issue.

I am relatively new to linux does anybody know what I can do, where I can look to resolve this issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

NJF

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dse dse-demos dse-hive dse-pig
Recommended packages:
  sun-java6-jre
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dse dse-demos dse-full dse-hive dse-pig
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 323 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 39.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main dse all 3.1.4-1 [5,638 kB]
Get:2 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main dse-hive all 3.1.4-1 [1,392 B]                                                                     
Get:3 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main dse-demos all 3.1.4-1 [26.3 MB]                                                                    
Get:4 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main dse-pig all 3.1.4-1 [1,386 B]                                                                      
Get:5 http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main dse-full all 3.1.4-1 [9,840 B]                                                                     
Fetched 31.9 MB in 43s (726 kB/s)                                                                                                                           
Selecting previously unselected package dse.
(Reading database ... 188939 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dse (from .../archives/dse_3.1.4-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dse-hive.
Unpacking dse-hive (from .../dse-hive_3.1.4-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dse-demos.
Unpacking dse-demos (from .../dse-demos_3.1.4-1_all.deb) ...  
Selecting previously unselected package dse-pig.
Unpacking dse-pig (from .../dse-pig_3.1.4-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dse-full.
Unpacking dse-full (from .../dse-full_3.1.4-1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up dse (3.1.4-1) ...
chgrp: cannot access `/etc/dse/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg': No such file or directory   
dpkg: error processing dse (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dse-hive:
 dse-hive depends on dse (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dse-hive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dse-demos:
 dse-demos depends on dse-hive (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse-hive is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dse-demos (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dse-pig:
 dse-pig depends on dse (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dse-pig (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dse-full:
 dse-full depends on dse (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse is not configured yet.
 dse-full depends on dse-hive (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse-hive is not configured yet.
 dse-full depends on dse-pig (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse-pig is not configured yet.
 dse-full depends on dse-demos (= 3.1.4-1); however:
  Package dse-demos is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing dse-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dse
 dse-hive
 dse-demos
 dse-pig
 dse-full
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: NJF did the below answer work?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you have a partial install on the system. Lets see what is there right now:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep dse
```

Depending on what is there, remove the remaining packages and data with (I assume you are ok with a complete uninstall):

```
apt-get purge dse-libcassandra dse-libhadoop  dse-libhive dse-liblog4j dse-libmahout dse-libpig dse-libsqoop dse-libsolr dse-libtomcat dse
```

That should allow you to reinstall.