# DSE Config Issueed

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Used 4.8.4 installer to install Datastax Enterprise on Ubuntu 12.

On starting dse service, I get an error in the /var/log/cassandra/system.log that says, "can't find /etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg".

I've set every HADOOP_CONF_DIR that I can find to /etc/dse/hadoop.

Two questions:
1)  What environment variable is the code using to try to find taskcontroller.cfg

2)  Where is the source code, so I could search for taskcontroller.cfg myself?

Comment: Per this post it seems you may have an incomplete install of DSE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476680/installing-dse-3-1-dependency how did you install? I'm not sure it uses an environmental varuable but in my install the file sits in the `/resources/hadoop/conf/taskcontroller.cfg` directory 2) hadoop cassandra integration in DSE is proprietary software and I wouldn't recommend trying to code dive the hadoop source for this one (I'm usually for code diving but in this case I think it's not a good use of your time). Are you actually trying to use the bundled DSE Hadoop stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `taskcontroller.cfg` must be in the directory you mentioned, that is `/etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg`. This file is required only when you use Kerberos authentication. Additionally, there are also other requirements for this file:

- it must be owned by root
- it must have the same group as DSE daemon
- it must be writable only by root
- it must not be empty

Anyway, the installation script should have setup everything properly. As far as I know, there is no way to customise the location of this file.

Comment: Ok.  I just copied the file from its post-installer location /etc/dse/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg to /etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg with the permissions described above, and I got past the error.  I started with a datastax amazon ami-15cbe87f, then re-ran the latest datastax installer DataStaxEnterprise-4.8.4.2016011118-linux-x64-installer.run.  (On Ubuntu 12 node.)  "The installation script should have setup everything properly" was not the case.